# Posting a large amount of data (~500k to 2MB) to IIS

Tags: c#, javascript, post

Users are posting large amounts of text to my website (500k-2MB) range, and for certain users (almost always geographically very far away like Australia) the server is not receiving all of the data (example, they post 600k the server receives 500k).

My suspicion is the post is timing out while sending the data.

My thought to solve this is to compress the contents client side and send a much smaller packet to my server.  Using http://blog.istepaniuk.com/client-side-compression-with-javascript/. I was able do this, but the algorithm degrades horrendously on a 2mb file brining my server to it's knees.  I have been unable to get GZIP/deflate working (based off of http://problemsolverblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/integration-of-js-deflate-with-other.html)

Questions

1. What would the recommended technique be for "posting" data at this size
2. If the recommended solution is to use client side (JS) compression and server side (C#) decompression has anyone done this successfully with available libraries? If so which ones.

** There are a few similar questions on SO, but I have found their answers incomplete/lacking for my needs. ([Using XHR to send large amounts of data via POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374152/using-xhr-to-send-large-amounts-of-data-via-post), [Compressing HTTP Post Data sent from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031968/compressing-http-post-data-sent-from-browser),

Comment: Have you added a long timeout to your web.config? `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="1536000"/>` Are there errors in your eventLog on the server?

Comment: I had the timeout out at 300, I will bump it to 3600 and see what happens.  Of course like any good hard to replicate error I go days between issues.  There is nothing in the IIS logs, but I do log the partial posts. (and thanks).

Comment: Why not cut the message to smaller chunks, eg. 100k and send them asynchronously and then combine on server side? The other thing should be taken in consideration here is anty-flooding protection on server.